# Loading PDF in Ext.Window

Tags: servlets, extjs

I have a servlet that returns a PDF. What i trying do is loading the PDF to Ext.Window. Below is the sample source

```
            Ext.getCmp('hisAmpPhyWin').load(
                    {
                        url:'servlet/Servlet/',
                        params: {xhtml:xhtmlData},
                        text: 'Loading PDF...',
                        scripts: false
                    });
```

Where 'hisAmpPhyWin' is a Ext.Window instance.

The thing is its showing the PDF content (i mean ascii characters) not the actual PDF in the browser.

Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be better off using an `IFRAME` tag for this.

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
  title: 'PDF Content',
  width: 420,
  height: 320,
  plain:true,
  html: String.format(
      '<iframe src="servlet/Servlet?p1={0}&p2={1}" width="400" height="300" />',
      xhtmlData.p1, xhtmlData.p2)
})
win.show();
```

Note: A browser **only** opens your data as PDF if it knows the **content type** is `application/pdf`, in here you are using the AJAX `.load()` method which *ignores* the content type coming back from the servlet response, however if you refer to it directly using an IFRAME the browser will apply the correct [MIME format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

Dont forget to make sure **every instance of your window is destroyed** (`closeAction = 'close'`, which is set by default), otherwise it'll keep opening up the same PDF document over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it natively, but there is a really good UX that should do it.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?23983-ux.Media-.Flash-Flex-Components-2.1.2&highlight=ux.Media

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create({
        title: 'My PDF',
        xtype: 'panel',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        items: {
            xtype: 'box',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'iframe',
                style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%',
                src: '/files/pdf-sample.pdf'
            }
        },
        renderTo: 'output'
    });
});
```